# Python Selenium WebDriver problem to parse tradingview.com

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, parsing, selenium-webdriver, click

I am currently using Selenium WebDriver to parse https://www.tradingview.com/screener/ site.

I want to find Filters button and click it.
The source of this element:

```
<div class="tv-screener-toolbar__button tv-screener-toolbar__button--options tv-screener-toolbar__button--filters apply-common-tooltip common-tooltip-fixed" data-name="screener-filter" data-role="button">
    Filters
</div>
```

The problem is: I can not find this element.

```
driver.get(' https://www.tradingview.com/screener/')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Filters'"))).click()
#or
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@name='screener-filter']"). click()
```

The error **“Message: no such element: Unable to locate element {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@name='screener-filter']"}”** occurs.

And the same problem is for any element. Looks like Selenium can not find elements on this page.
Can you please recommend me how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: issue is here `//div[@name='screener-filter']` , it's not name attribute, it is `data-name`. probably the below answer should solve the query

Answer (score 1):

Your first locator is missing `]` while the second command is missing explicit wait and there is a wrong attribute name there. `name` instead of `data-name`.
So you can try using

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Filters']"))).click()
#or
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-name='screener-filter']"))).click()
```